# How do I get better at finding algorithms for problems?

Tags: algorithm

In programming, a lot of problems require you to find an efficient algorithm. So, if I want to be able to craft good algorithms that satisfy such criteria, what could I do? Is there any resources that help in training your algorithm development skills?

Help appreciated thanks!

Edit: I know that this question received hate, probably because it is not very agreeable to StackOverflow policies. Nevertheless, thanks Dylan Wright for taking the time to answer!

Comment: The question did not receive "hate", just enforcement of the policy. Such a question does not belong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So most people are probably going to rip you apart for asking this question.  No worries, just ignore.  Algorithm go hand in hand with data structures in large amounts of data and/or some repetitive task. The key to the algorithm has a lot of different possibilities so there is no real straight forward answers.  It mostly goes with what is the solution to what you are trying to improve.  An algorithm is something as simple as parsing through an array of street addresses for your address application.  To understand algorithms is really knowing what are common algorithms and how they work.  Then you can educate yourself and maybe create one of your own.  You should do some research on this.
To start look on blog sites like Medium.com
https://medium.com/@_marcos_otero/the-real-10-algorithms-that-dominate-our-world-e95fa9f16c04 
Or just Google
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/top-algorithms-and-data-structures-for-competitive-programming/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I run into this problem whenever I solve questions because I can't get an algorithm and even if I do, it is not efficient

Comment: Algorithms really can be anything. So don't worry about specific predefined Algorithms you've probably created a few without even really knowing that you did so.

Comment: Thought I would add this as well.  It seems that you're looking for education.  Stack Overflow is more a Q/A forum and people try to discourage educational questions.  Why, I don't know it's our work environment I guess.  Keeps it cleaner maybe, however there are things out there like FreeCodeCamp that helps, here is an article about algorithms on FreeCodeCamp https://medium.freecodecamp.org/10-common-data-structures-explained-with-videos-exercises-aaff6c06fb2b I was trying to give this earlier just couldn't find it, it's been found.  Good luck to you.